# How to match all namespace's element by Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, namespaces, nokogiri

I want to find a element like this.

```
xml1 = '<period>2017-02-10</period>'
```

or

```
xml2 = <<XML
<root xmlns:xbrli="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xbrli:period>2017-02-10</period>
</root>
XML
```

I can select the element by:

```
  def period_from_xml(xml)
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
    period_element = if doc.namespaces.keys.include?('xmlns:xbrli')
      doc.at_css("xbrli|period")
    else
      doc.at_css("period")
    end
  end

  period_from_xml(xml1)
  # => <period>2017-02-10</period>
  period_from_xml(xml2)
  # => <xbrli:period>2017-02-10</period>
```

I know `Nokogiri::XML::Document#remove_namespaces!`, but I don't want to use it, because another place I need it.

Maybe duplicating the `doc` and `doc_without_namespaces` is good idea?

Is there a easy and simple way to handle this situation?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Your input XML sample needs to be better as it's missing the namespace declarations you're trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<root xmlns:xbrli="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <period>2017-02-10</period>
  <xbrli:period>2017-02-11</period>
</root>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

doc.search('period,xbrli|period').map(&:text) # => ["2017-02-10", "2017-02-11"]
```

`'period,xbrli|period'` in CSS means "find `"period"` or `"xbrli:period"`.

See "[How to avoid joining all text from Nodes when scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594656/how-to-avoid-joining-all-text-from-nodes-when-scraping)" also.

Comment: Sorry, my first question had not enough information about what I want to know. I edited my question.